# Writing strings to binary files in C

Tags: c, string, binaryfiles, fread

I have some code that writes a `char *` to a binary file like so:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(path, "wb");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open file at path: %s. %s\n", path, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return;
}

fwrite("Hello", 6, 1, fp);
```

The problem is that when I then read from that file like so:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(path, "rb");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open file at path: %s. %s\n", path, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return;
}


char *str;
fread(str, 6, 1, fp);
printf("Got str: %s\n", str);
```

I get different results e.g. `Oello` or `Mello`. What is going on?

Comment: you never set the `char* str` or am I wrong?

Comment: Post **all** your code.  Your posted code has you reading into `id`:  `fread(id, 6, 1, fp);` (*maybe* reading - you don't check the return value...), but you emit the contents of whatever the uninitialized variable `str` points to:  `printf("Got str: %s\n", str);`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I am reading into the str variable. The id comes from a previous implementation that I changed to str so I could test what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is incorrect:

```
char *str;
fread(str, 6, 1, fp);
printf("Got str: %s\n", str);
```

`char *str;` creates an *uninitialized* character pointer.  Where's the memory that it points to?

```
char str[ 7 ];
fread(str, sizeof( str ) - 1, 1, fp);
str[ sizeof( str ) - 1 ] = '\0';
printf("Got str: %s\n", str);
```

would be better, although it still doesn't check the return value from `fread()` to ensure data is actually read.

Comment: Ahh. Yes my bad. I assumed that the memory following the pointer would be populated safely by `read`. So that `read` would create the char array and set the str* to point to it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated memory for `str`

```
char *str ; // You haven't allocated memory for it , Do
str=malloc(6*sizeof *str);
```

Then do

```
fread(str, 6, 1, fp);
```

Also, if the write and read happens in the same translation unit, you should do

```
fclose(fp); // to flush the output buffer and close the file descriptor
```

before reading from the file